# How to force Linux bridge to output frame on multiple interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, bridge, sniffing

I have a Linksys E2500 router running Tomato v1.28 (Linux kernel 2.6.22.19, no USB drive capability) that is functioning in bridge mode to connect three interfaces:

```
root@TomatoE2500Host:/# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.586d8fb74454       no              eth1
                                                        eth2
                                                        vlan1
```

- eth1 is the 2.4 Ghz wireless (access point mode - Xbox is only wireless host)
- eth2 is the 5.0 Ghz wireless (client mode to main gateway router / other devices)
- vlan1 is the 4x LAN ethernet ports (Windows 10 desktop is only wired host)

The bridge works fine for 'normal' purposes, but I am trying to use the Windows desktop running Wireshark to sniff packets being sent between the Xbox and the main gateway.

```
root@TomatoE2500Host:/# brctl showmacs br0
port no mac addr                is local?       ageing timer
  3     00:01:36:1f:e4:5c       yes                0.00
  2     4c:0b:be:3e:5b:2d       no                36.09
  1     58:6d:8f:b7:44:54       yes                0.00
  2     58:6d:8f:b7:44:56       yes                0.00
  3     68:37:e9:50:ce:f7       no               100.34
  3     6c:56:97:04:1e:3f       no               100.63
  3     a0:cc:2b:ad:46:d1       no               224.45
  3     b0:39:56:69:aa:eb       no                 1.02
  1     f4:6d:04:4f:9f:6a       no                 0.01
```

Understandably, frames/packets from the Xbox (4c:0b:be:3e:5b:2d) on *eth1* (port 2) are only getting pushed to the gateway (b0:39:56:69:aa:eb) on *eth2* (port 3) while the wired desktop (f4:6d:04:4f:9f:6a) on *vlan1* (port 1) is getting left in the dark.

**How do I force frames from the *eth1* interface to be broadcast on *vlan1* interface, in addition to the default/needed *eth2*?**

It is as if I need a [MAC Flooding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_flooding) attack on myself to force the bridge into broadcasting packets on multiple interfaces, instead of relying on its forwarding database (FDB) shown above.  But there has to be a better way to enable this, right?

Comment: Simplest way is not to try to make the bridge do that, but instead put something between the xbox and the bridge (laptop, or network namespace on the router), configure forwarding and/or NAT, and wireshark/tcpdump there.

Comment: If you have `tcpdump` handy on your Linksys box, you could capture directly on-device.

Answer (score 2):

The forwarding database only supports mapping unicast addresses to one port (which is apropriate for 'unicast' having one destination). There are other methods:

- You can use iptables' `TEE` target, as in [this SF thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/900778/mirroring-traffic-on-a-linux-bridge-to-a-monitoring-interface). For this to work you'll need to enable bridge iptables filtering first:

  ```
  ip link set dev br0 type bridge nf_call_iptables 1
  ```
- Similarly, you can *probably* use the `dup` action in nftables [bridge table](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Bridge_filtering):

  ```
  iifname "br0" dup to "eth0"
  ```
- As in [this article](https://backreference.org/2014/06/17/port-mirroring-with-linux-bridges/), you can use *tc* with "action mirred" and some other incomprehensible parameters.
- You can use a userspace program to capture packets on the bridge and forward them through another interface, either raw or encapsulated (e.g. inside a TZSP or ERSPAN tunnel). One example is [RSniffer](https://github.com/vponomarev/RSniffer). On the receiving side, Wireshark will automatically recognize the encapsulated packets.
- You can run *tcpdump* via SSH and feed its output to a local Wireshark UI:

  ```
  ssh router tcpdump -n -i eth2 -s 65535 -w - -U | wireshark -k -i -
  ```

  (Yes web says you need a USB drive for the "full" 2 MB tcpdump, but *surely* there's a lite version somewhere (something like `dumpcap`)? You don't need any of the packet analysis code, for example. It seems like this sort of thing shouldn't need a binary larger than 10 kB...)
- As a last resort, you can buy another switch or router which has native port-mirroring support. (For example, managed switches tend to have a "mirror port" or a "SPAN port", and RouterOS-based devices have native support for tcpdump-like capture through a TZSP tunnel.)

Note, though, that your Linksys very likely has *two* bridges stacked – the "vlan1" device (your 4x LAN ports) often represents a hardware switch which has its own independent FDB, so traffic between these ports doesn't reach the software Linux bridge at all.

Comment: I think my Linux kernel version (2.6.22.19, added to OP) and sparse modules are a limiting factor for some of these solutions.  To your second bullet, [nftables](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/What_is_nftables%3F) is only available for Linux kernels >= 3.13, but something similar to the first bullet should be possible for me using the nftables forerunner commands [ebtables/iptables](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html) if only I can get the iptables hooks to indeed fire in bridge mode.   ...(Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) ...   To that end, `ip link set dev br0 type bridge nf_call_iptables 1` throws `Error: either "dev" is duplicate, or "type" is a garbage.` and the more-general `ip link set help` reveals no `type` option.  This all from `ip -V` of `ip utility, iproute2-ss070710`.   I do not seem to have the [bridge-nf](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/what.html) module available either (Additionally, with iptables v1.3.8 I'll have to stick to the ROUTE target instead of TEE that came in [v1.4.8](https://netfilter.org/projects/iptables/files/changes-iptables-1.4.8.txt)).  Will keep digging.

Comment: The same setting should be available via sysctl, although the exact parameter seems to have changed (https://serverfault.com/questions/162366/iptables-bridge-and-forward-chain).

Comment: An [exhaustive sysctl listing](http://freetexthost.com/gmioeqsuok) search (which I have to access via the [/proc/sys](https://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/changing-variables-no-sysctl.71376/) file system) returned no parameters remotely related to ‘nf_call_iptables’.     …(Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d)…  On a whim, tried moving the Xbox to the gateway’s 5Ghz access point (alongside the Tomato E2500 router’s _eth2_), then attempting to promiscuously bridge from _eth2_ to _vlan1_ using `ip link set eth2 promisc on` then `ebtables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 4C:0B:BE:3E:5B:2D -j dnat --to-destination F4:6D:04:4F:9F:6A` and `ebtables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 4C:0B:BE:3E:5B:2D -j dnat --to-destination F4:6D:04:4F:9F:6A` but packet counts show these rules are not getting triggered either.  Will try `tc` or remotely controlled `tcpdump` next.